# Built-in Speaker and Microphone not working on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

So as of this morning, the builtin microphone and speaker, along with headset speaker and microphone have stopped working on my Ubuntu 20.04. I have an asus zenbook. I have a dualboot installation (Ubuntu and Windows), microphone and speaker work perfectly fine on windows, so I assume that the hardware is fine.
On Ubuntu, I connected a display with speaker to the laptop through HDMI and the sound is played fine on the display. Laptop's builtin speaker still doesn't work. I've tried deleting and purging alsa and pulseaudio and reinstalling them, several times , but nothing changed.
I checked alsa mixer and everything seems fine:
Alsa Mixer
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, windows sometimes sets flags on sound devices. I had recently used windows, so some sort of flag was set and ubuntu couldn't work with the sound system anymore. I logged back into windows, removed and reinstalled sound drivers and the problem went away!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leave ALSA alone and play only with Pulse audio volume control (pavucontrol). You have to install it on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.
Info from [Learn how audio on Linux works](https://opensource.com/article/17/1/linux-plays-sound)

> pavucontrol is a dynamic panel consisting of five tabs:

```
Configuration: activates sound cards and defines the usage profile. On my desktop machine, for instance, I generally have HDMI de-activated and my built-in analog card on and set to Stereo Duplex. You won't often use this panel; it's mostly something you set once and forget about.

Input Devices: currently available input devices (anything capable of making sound). These usually consist of a microphone (very common on laptops, which usually have a built-in mic for the webcam), a line-in, and a "monitor" device for whatever is currently playing on your system (more on that later).

Output Devices: currently available output targets, such as desktop speakers and headphones (plugged into Line Out ports), and USB headsets.

Recording: currently active recording sessions. This might be a web browser looking for sound input for a video chat session, or it might be a recording application like Audacity. If it's got a socket open for sound, it's here.

Playback: currently active sounds streams being played. If it's meant to be heard, then it's here.
```